# EV3 square pattern motion

Tags: ev3, programming

I'm trying to make my EV3 robot move in a square path, and an infinity path.

I've tried [this code](http://thetechnicgear.com/2014/04/howto-build-3-wheels-holonomic-robot-using-lego/) for a square path but it's not working.

[image: Image of a triangular robot with omni wheels]

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part is not working?

Comment: Please send pictures of your robot and explain how it moves. Whether it uses legs or wheels or fans is necessary information for the question.

Comment: @DavidLechner, I mean when I download the program and start it the robot isn't moving in square path

Comment: @mindstormsboi, ok done!

Comment: I don't understand how that robot with triangular-aligned wheels can moe in a straight path, did that link tell you to put the wheels that way? you should put the wheels like a plain old car, it will do better. if this helps let me know and I'll post as answer.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Looks like [omni wheels](https://www.robotshop.com/de/en/58mm-plastic-omni-wheel-compatible-servos-lego-mindstorms-nxt.html)...

Comment: Let's start with something simpler.  Have you managed to get it to move in a Triangular pattern?  (i.e. to prove that you can drive it correctly - I *believe* that the ratio of the motor speeds should be the `Cosine` of the angle between the wheel and the direction of travel, so an Equilateral Triangle will require ±1 for 1 wheel, and ±0.5 for the others, while a Square will require various combinations of ±1, ±√(3/4), ±0.5, and 0.  Although, I guess you could also manage an Equilateral Triangle with ±√(3/4) for 2 wheels, and 0 for the other...)

Comment: "but it's not working." Please specify exactly how it is not working, i.e. what is it doing instead of the expected outcome. A video would probably be the best, but a graphical representation could also enable us to help you.

Comment: if its not moving in square path, what shape or direction is it moving in instead? edit the question to explain what is going on.